# Algorithm: How to find the positions of a certain value in a matrice (2 dimensional)

Tags: algorithm, matrix, find, element

I'm trying to find an algorithm which, given two natural numbers n,m  (m<=n), let A=[1,...n][1...m] whose elements are natural numbers. If we know that all A's elements are ascendingly sorted for each column and each row, meaning:

```
A[i,j] < A[i,j+1]
```

and

`A[i,j] < A[i+1,j]`

the algorithm needed should return the positions (X,Y) for which the value K is found. 
Additionally, I need to find it's complexity, but that can be calculated by its algorithm.
Is this problem solved? Which algorithm would that be?

Comment: Are the rows and columns *sorted* or *strictly ascending*?

Comment: The question says both. It confused me since it can be sorted without being ascending. I suppose having them ascending would match the indications above. So, not just sorted.

Comment: Ok let's go with that, it's more useful than merely sorted.